# MSBuild: Setting a preprocessor define based on property updated in a target

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

So we have a variable which is currently an environment var and on loading of the sln it uses that variable to determine which project is active and selects certain things specific to that project (preprocessor define)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GameItentifier>$(GAMEIDENIFIER_ENV_VAR)</GameItentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The above works with the below ItemDefinitionGroup but we would like to move away from environment variables

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>        
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(GameItentifier)' == 'game1'">GAME_1;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(GameItentifier)' == 'game2'">GAME_2;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

So this preprocess define lets call it GAME_1 or GAME_2 gets set. We have a dll we have created where we can load variables from an ini. So inside a target I can update GameItentifier to either game 1 or game 2 without needing the environment variable.

So my issue is I can't get the preprocess to recognise the change. So in our earliest target I set this. This target runs as the message output shows up and all subsequent checks of GameItentifier have shown they update correctly.

```
  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$bin\IniVars.dll" TaskName="msbuild.IniVarsInit" />
  <Target Name="SetGameItentifier">
    <IniVarsInit>
      <Output TaskParameter="IniVars" ItemName="IniVars"/>
    </IniVarsInit>    
    <PropertyGroup>
      <GameItentifier>%(IniVars.GameIdentifier)</GameItentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="GameItentifier: $(GameItentifier)" />
  </Target>
```

So my question is how would it be possible to get those preprocessor values set from the GameItentifier value from the override rather than the environment var?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you take a moment to tell us how the problem is going? We are always here to give you any support in time.

Answer (score 0):

> MSBuild: Setting a preprocessor define based on property updated in a
> target

The traditional way cannot solve your problem. We suggest that you can create a msbuild script, and then call **msbuild.exe** to run the script directly to implement your method.

**Reason**

Make sure that the target **SetGameItentifier** executes before the whole build process and make sure that MSBuild reads the property `GameItentifier` after you assign the new value to it. In your function, there is no way to pass the new value from the custom target **SetGameItentifier** because MSBuild reads all properties very early. And at that time, target always runs after MSBuild reads all properties including `GameItentifier`. So your new value `GameItentifier` is always after MSbuild reads the property `GameItentifier` under the condition.

So the condition is null and always `false`. So the issue persists.

**You should make sure that the target SetGameItentifier executes before the whole build process so that it will succeed.**

**Solution**

The following is my method:

**1)** first create a script called `test.proj` file and write the core content into `test.proj` file rather than in a custom target file:

**Note**: you should delete that target and then put **SetGameItentifier** into `test.proj` directly

```
<Project>

    <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$bin\IniVars.dll" TaskName="msbuild.IniVarsInit" />
     
    <Target Name="SetGameItentifier">   
        <IniVarsInit>
          <Output TaskParameter="IniVars" ItemName="IniVars"/>
        </IniVarsInit>    
        <PropertyGroup>
          <GameItentifier>%(IniVars.GameIdentifier)</GameItentifier>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Message Text="GameItentifier: $(GameItentifier)" />
     <MSBuild Projects="xxx\xxx.vcxproj(the path of the vcxproj file)" Targets="Build" Properties="GameItentifier=$(GameItentifier)"></MSBuild>   
      </Target>

</Project>
```

**2)** Then keep the other content you show unchanged in the `xxx.vcxproj` file and only add a extra target called `showPara` to show the `PreprocessorDefinitions` property.

add this in `vcxproj` file:

```
<Target Name="showPara" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="%(ClCompile.PreprocessorDefinitions)==============$(GameItentifier)"></Message>
</Target>
```

**3)** open [Developer Command Prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) and enter

```
msbuild xxx\test.proj -t:SetGameItentifier -v:detailed
```

Then you will see the output just as we expected.

[image]

===============================

**Besides**, you could also create a bat file to build automatically.

**1)** Create a file called `build.bat` and then add these in it:

```
        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" 
        ECHO Bulding !!!
        
        ECHO Building ...
        msbuild C:\xxx\test.rpoj -t:SetGameItentifier -v:detailed
```

**2)** When you click on it, it will build the specific file automatically.